# error while run android studio project

Tags: android, build

Below is my Gridle file ,
i tried every possible solution from stackoverflow other's question answare but it still showing same.

Error:

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

GRIDLE:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.mobilegts.redemption.evolution"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

Here is XML where it is used:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
</resources>
```

Some Other Error while changing minsdkversion to 11

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] C:\Users\Herry.android\build-cache\789f0b2db1622f43f20c9fb40bf82eb406ac929b\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

Comment: post your XML file where you're trying to use the borderless property

Comment: Why are you using jars when you can compile from maven repo?

Comment: There might be problem in your styles.xml file. You should post it too.

Comment: its a game , i dont have much knowledge about maven , its an eclipse project and i try to import it in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change buildToolsVersion to 23.0.2

Comment: You don't have to use lower buildToolsVersion. You can make it work with higher version also.

Comment: Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.2) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
<a href="fix.build.tools.version">Update Build Tools version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Herry/AndroidStudioProjects/android/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: then change compileSdkVersion to your higer version

Comment: try this add  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:23.0.2' instead  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'